# SQL date filter

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, timestamp

I ran this following query and somehow I feel the results are wrong.

```
SQL> select to_char(starttime,'dd-mm-YYYY hh24:mi:ss') 
from report 
where dateofmonth between 
    to_timestamp_tz('22-Apr-2013 12:00:00','dd-mm-YYYY hh24:mi:ss') 
    and to_timestamp_tz ('23-Apr-2013 14:00:00','dd-mm-YYYY hh24:mi:ss');

TO_CHAR(STARTTIME,
--------------------
23-04-2013 22:43:59
23-04-2013 13:43:37

SQL> select to_timestamp_tz(starttime,'dd-mm-YYYY hh24:mi:ss') 
from report 
where dateofmonth between 
    to_timestamp_tz('22-Apr-2013 12:00:00','dd-mm-YYYY hh24:mi:ss') 
    and to_timestamp_tz ('23-Apr-2013 14:00:00','dd-mm-YYYY hh24:mi:ss');

TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(STARTTIME,'DD-MM-YYYYHH24:MI:SS')
-------------------------------------------------
23-APR-13 10.43.59 PM -07:00
23-APR-13 01.43.37 PM -07:00
```

I am not sure why the 10 PM time is coming up in the result.

Comment: It is because `dateofmonth` is insensitive to time of day, and only checks that the date is right?

Comment: can u help me make it sensitive to time also? i am not sure how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manjit,

You are selecting starttime column, but the where clause has dateofmonth column. Select both starttime and dateofmonth in your query and check if it is giving the correct result.